# Resharper Overriding VS Functionality

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I downloaded the trial of Resharper and installed it today. The first thing it asked me was that version of shortcut keys I wanted to use. It asked me if I wanted to override some standard Visual Studio shortcut keys. My answer was @#$# no!

However, the first thing I did was a Ctrl-Dot on a class reference that was missing an import. Immediately, the Resharper context menu came up which is similar to the VS one, but is missing the item for automatically adding the import.

How do I keep Resharper from usurping VS functionality?

***Edit: Ouch! After using this thing for a couple of hours, I've realized that it has totally overridden loads of VS functionality. This thing is awful. I just want to use the toolset, I don't want a completely new IDE. If I wanted a different IDE, I'd go out and buy one. How do I turn off all Visual Studio integration except for the menu that lets me run the tools?***

Comment: Do you even spare some time reading its documentation or view its settings? They simply provide you many options.

Comment: Obviously they do. I went through all the settings and turned off as much as I could find, but there's still loads of functionality that I can't figure out how to switch off.

Comment: Crippling ReSharper like this is like removing the peddles and gears from a bike because your legs are used to walking. Embrace all the extra power ReSharper gives you. If you don't get on with it then uninstall it and continue walking with Visual Studio while the rest of us do wheelies with ReSharper :)

Comment: I've been using resharper for a few days now. It's both extremely powerful, and extremely frustrating. It doesn't settle for merely giving you a bunch of new tools to play with, it literally takes over your entire IDE and goes as far as recolouring the editors. If it simply added context menus to the existing screens etc. it wouldn't be a problem, but they way it is, they might as well have created an entirely new IDE. Is there no way to turn off all the functionality simply? I mean, I'm having to uninstall the whole bloody app just to get normal VS functionality back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different settings you can turn on and off to allow Visual Studio to behave more like Visual Studio when Resharper is in action. What's I've learned to do is just turn it on when I want to use it, and turn it off when I want to use Visual Studio.

Tools -> Options -> Resharper Ultimate General -> Suspend / Resume Now